# What is the need of using comparator function inside structure?

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, comparator

[I cannot understand what is happening inside the struct comp and the bool operator() function. And how does the the map and iterator behave if I write
`map<int,int,comp>` ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxjdM.jpg)

Comment: Because you are setting the property again. Recursively. You need a backing *field* if you want to use this form of properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties are recursively calling themselves. Take your `Sid` property

```
public int Sid
{
    set 
    {
        if (Sid <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Id must be positive."); // here, also validation wrong--use value
        else Sid = value; // here
    }
    get { return Sid; } //here
}
```

Where I've marked, the getter and setter are invoking `Sid` again. This causes them to be called recursively until the stack overflows. If you want to perform validation in a property, you'll need to use explicit backing fields:

```
private int _sid;     
public int Sid
{
    set 
    {
        if (value <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Id must be positive.");
        else _sid = value;
    }
    get { return _sid; }
}
```

You should also consider taking action in your setter when validation fails. Simply outputting to the console is *unexpected*. The user gets no indication (via code) that something is wrong. Consider throwing an exception instead.

```
private int _sid;     
public int Sid
{
    set 
    {
        if (value <= 0)
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Id must be positive.");
        _sid = value;
    }
    get => _sid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you get a stack overflow because your setter recursively calls your setter recursively calls your setter recursively calls your setter......

you need to have a backing field for this, like so:

```
public class Student {
    private int _sid;
    public int Sid
    {
        set 
        {
            if (value <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Id must be positive.");
            else _sid = value;
        }
        get { return _sid; }
    }
```